# Is every fibration locally trivial?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, fibration

Is every fibration locally trivial? If there is counter example, what is different between locally trivial different and non one ? Or Does it have condition for determine a fibration is locally trivial?

Comment: When you say "locally trivial" do you mean "locally isomorphic to a product fibration" or "locally homotopic to a product fibration" ?

Comment: @Max I mean “locally diffeomorphic to a product fibration “ , my main problem is that I have fibration $\pi:M\longrightarrow T^2$ ,the I want to prove that induced homomorphism of cohomology group is injective, so I am going to khnow is it related to locally trivial property of fibration.

Comment: Oh so you're asking about the smooth setting. I don't know about that, but in the continuous setting (replacing "diffeomorphic" by "homeomorphic") it's not true

Comment: See [this answer](/a/2291737) for example.

Comment: @user10354138 it mean if smooth fibration is compact with compact base space is fiber bundle?